# Ubuntu 20.04 Crashing every 1-2 days

Tags: 20.04, crash, nas, amd-ryzen

About a week ago I switched a computer I use as a NAS from windows to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and since then I have been having issues with the NAS crashing every 1-2 days.

When the NAS crashes the whole screen is frozen including mouse movement. Even REISUB doesn't reboot the system. I always end up having to press the reset button on the computer.

The NAS runs a Ryzen 7 1700 processor so I thought it might have been a power state issue. Most of the advice I found about this said to disable the C6 Power state in my motherboards BIOS but my motherboard (Asus x370-f strix) doesn't seem to have an option for that.
I did find someone using MX Linux who said that they disabled the C6 Power state with the command `cpupower idle-set --disable c6`.
I tried this but I am still having the issue.

I ran the command `journalctl | grep error`
after the last crash and these are the only error messages from the day it last crashed.

```
Jun 03 21:22:22 NAS-PC kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jun 03 21:22:25 NAS-PC systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Jun 03 21:22:26 NAS-PC gnome-session[1435]: gnome-session-binary[1435]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jun 03 21:22:26 NAS-PC gnome-session-binary[1435]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jun 03 21:22:33 NAS-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2177]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
```

I am fairly new to Linux so I have no idea if this is the command I should be using for error logs, please let me know if there is a better method of checking for errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

EDIT: Here are the results from the commands I was asked to run.

```
nas@NAS-PC:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
3803
nas@NAS-PC:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.0Gi        11Gi       5.0Mi       2.2Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

nas@NAS-PC:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
nas@NAS-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 3803
       date: 01/22/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_A1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMW16GX4M2C3200C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMW16GX4M2C3200C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 768KiB
       capacity: 768KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: e
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: f
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

EDIT: The motherboard is an asus rog stix x370-f gaming.
Here is the result from `grep -i sdb2 /var/log/syslog*`
It doesn't show anything from the time of the crash on Jun 3 but I have actually had a few crashes today, when trying to setup memtest on a usb stick. Hopefully the data that is here is useful.

```
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 09:55:54 NAS-PC kernel: [    1.566219]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 09:55:54 NAS-PC kernel: [    4.959148] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 09:55:54 NAS-PC kernel: [    5.499027] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:00:29 NAS-PC kernel: [    1.554147]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:00:29 NAS-PC kernel: [    4.965393] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:00:29 NAS-PC kernel: [    5.441670] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:08:32 NAS-PC kernel: [    1.546202]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:08:32 NAS-PC kernel: [    4.973591] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:08:32 NAS-PC kernel: [    5.444522] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:18:38 NAS-PC kernel: [    1.542013]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:18:38 NAS-PC kernel: [    4.934979] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:18:38 NAS-PC kernel: [    5.395831] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:30:06 NAS-PC kernel: [    1.549958]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:30:06 NAS-PC kernel: [    4.848546] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  4 10:30:06 NAS-PC kernel: [    5.322608] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Binary file /var/log/syslog.1 matches
```

I have 3 drives in the system: 1x 120gb ssd, 2x 6tb hdd setup in RAID 1 with mdadm. None of them have windows installed on them.
Here is the result from `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.48 MiB, 58159104 bytes, 113592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 138.93 MiB, 145657856 bytes, 284488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55.43 MiB, 58114048 bytes, 113504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 51.4 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 162.89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 32.9 MiB, 33644544 bytes, 65712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 5.47 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6002FFWX-6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 25D7A7C5-BE1E-4DE1-BE76-AF1CCCA56E55

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 11721043967 11721041920  5.5T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1FFE61F6-6E4D-45CD-80EB-61F0F8CFF851

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 234440703 233390080 111.3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 5.47 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6002FFWX-6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 78290624-A970-432A-978C-B8D7F9A79561

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 11721043967 11721041920  5.5T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/md0: 5.47 TiB, 6001038196736 bytes, 11720777728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/loop8: 32.1 MiB, 33660928 bytes, 65744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 141.4 MiB, 148254720 bytes, 289560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Here are the screenshots of DISKS Smart Data(The RAID Array itself obviously doesn't have any smart data)

[6.0TB RAID-1 Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heDP7.jpg)

[KINGSTON SA400S37120G (SBFK71E0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7jIe.jpg)

[WDC WD6002FFWX-68TZ4N0 (83.H0A83)(NCGWXW2V)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPets.jpg)

[WDC WD6002FFWX-68TZ4N0 (83.H0A83)(NCH9XLDS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVnik.jpg)

EDIT: Here is ls -al /var/crash. Cpupower-gui was part of my attempt to disable C6 power state I didn't end up using this application.

```
total 15744
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Jun  4 07:37  .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Feb 10 05:56  ..
-rw-r-----  1 nas      whoopsie    66768 Jun  2 11:52  _usr_bin_cpupower-gui.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 nas      whoopsie        0 Jun  2 11:52  _usr_bin_cpupower-gui.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Jun  2 11:52  _usr_bin_cpupower-gui.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 plex     whoopsie 16036359 May 30 02:15 '_usr_lib_plexmediaserver_Plex Media Server.998.crash'
```

EDIT: Here's a fresh `sudo lshw -C memory` The new RAM isn't on the QVL

```
      *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 5603
       date: 07/28/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-01-21 18:43+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2d1d5e352f0d063d660df2300e31f66bed027fa5)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-01-21 18:43+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2d1d5e352f0d063d660df2300e31f66bed027fa5) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_A1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2400C15D4/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 9321D353
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-01-21 18:43+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2d1d5e352f0d063d660df2300e31f66bed027fa5)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2021-01-21 18:43+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2d1d5e352f0d063d660df2300e31f66bed027fa5) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2400C15D4/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: 90216553
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 2e
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 768KiB
       capacity: 768KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2f
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 30
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Comment: I'd be looking at the lines before `EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` .. as that looks like the consequence of a problem from lines that precede it.  But if you're using it as a file-server (NAS), why are there lines relating to GNOME or a desktop?

Comment: Suspect BIOS or RAM. Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Ryzen's are very fussy about RAM. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @guiverc the only lines before that were from about 36hrs before the line you mentioned. As I said, I am fairly new to Linux and so I decided that Ubuntu desktop with a gui would be more user friendly for me to learn on.

Comment: To have no messages for 36 hours in the systemd journal (`journalctl`) shows a severe problem!  Are you sure? or are you limiting your thinking/results to portions (ie. `grep` causes only certain lines/areas to show) ... my box rarely goes 3 mins before detail being logged by systemd.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited my question to include the results from the commands you asked me to run. I am about to run memtest.

Comment: @guiverc I was using grep error. I just ran (journalctl) on it's own but there's about a million lines within the second of the EXT4-fs error line. Is there any way to narrow it down to just the relevant stuff?

Comment: @Tomupton Thank you for the data. You forgot to tell me the make/model of your computer or motherboard. Also, based on previous info, I'd like to see `grep -i sdb2 /var/log/syslog*`. If that output is large, post it to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL so I can review it.

Comment: @Tomupton Please edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l`. How many disks do you have on your system? Two? Do you have Windows on sda, and Ubuntu on sdb? Start the `Disks` app, and show me screenshots of the **SMART Data** window for both disks. The data window is scrollable, so it may take two screenshots for each disk to get it all.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question with the extra info you asked for. Also I was wondering which test I should run with memtest because there are a bunch of them.

Comment: @Tomupton Thanks for being so responsive. re: memtest... run the entire suite of tests... that is the default.

Comment: @Tomupton Please edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question. Should I update the bios before running memtest?

Comment: @Tomupton Although it'll take a little more time, run memtest first, and let's establish whether it fails or not. Then do the BIOS, and if memtest failed the first run, then rerun memtest and see if it works after the BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema Memtest failed with the old bios. I am now running a full backup and then I will update the bios and try again. If that fails, I do have another set of ddr4 that I can put in and try but I'd rather try the bios update first.

Comment: @Tomupton Good news! Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Tomupton Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I updated the bios and ran memtest again. It failed so I tried another set of ram and memtest passed with that installed. The memory I tried was in my main desktop which has an i7 9700k. I am now doing a memtest with the RAM that was in the NAS installed with the 9700k to see if the RAM is faulty or if it just doesn't play well with the memory controller on the Ryzen 7 1700. Do you still think it's worth checking the linux filesystem and increasing the swap size?

Comment: @Tomupton Yes, please check your file system, and increase the swap. If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema The memtest with the i7-9700k and the ram from the NAS failed. The NAS is still crashing even with the RAM that passed the memtest and the bigger swap. I am going to check the file system now.

Comment: @heynnema The file system seams fine no errors or warnings. I forgot to mention in my last comment that last night the computer woke me up because the graphics card fan seamed to set itself at full speed for whatever reason. I tried wiggling the mouse and pressing space but the screen wouldn't come on (The computer was in sleep mode). Don't know if that means anything to you but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @Tomupton I don't know if the transported RAM is compatible with your Ryzen CPU, and we may still be fighting the same problem. Do `sudo lshw -C memory` to get the new RAM model #. Check the updated MEMORY section of my answer, follow the link, check the CPU docs to determine your processor name, then view the memory compatibility docs to see if your current RAM is compatible. It may have different specs than what's required.

Comment: @Tomupton With the two machines, I may be confused about which one has the trouble. The i7-9700k (Intel processor?)(NAS?) ,or the Ryzen 7 1700 (AMD processor). Did the memtest fail on the problem machine again with the new RAM?

Comment: @heynnema The NAS has the Ryzen 7 1700. The computer with the i7 9700k is my PC. The RAM that is now in the NAS (The RAM that passed the memtest) was originally in my PC. I was still having problems with the NAS crashing despite using the memory that passed the memtest. Although I think it might have been due to the bios update changing some settings to do with power states which I had originally changed when I was trying to disable the C6 power state. I have set it back as I had it before the update and I haven't had a crash since. I'll just wait a day or so to make sure the problem is fixed.

Comment: @Tomupton Good news! I assume that the new BIOS, and it's settings, and discovery of the failing RAM via `memtest` solved the problem, unless I hear otherwise. If my answer helped to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema The NAS just crashed again. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Tomupton Show me a fresh `sudo lshw -C memory`. I want to check if that new RAM is on the supported list. Then, REMOVE one of the two DIMMs, so you'll be running on 8G. See if it crashes. If it DOES crash, switch DIMMs. Test again. Show me a fresh `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question with the fresh lshw -C memory. I think there might have been something wrong with the GPU because yesterday when I was using the NAS (I was using the actual computer not accessing it on the network) I started getting a bunch of visual glitches, artifacts and the like. I moved the GPU from my PC to the NAS and I haven't had any visual glitches or crashes so far. I want to see if the GPU was an issue before I take out a stick of RAM.

Comment: @Tomupton You're getting pretty good at this :-) You also found that the newer, faster RAM was not on the QVL list. 5 gold stars!

Comment: @heynnema I figured it out. After swapping the ram, all the problems I had were due to the GPU not being seated properly.

Comment: @Tomupton So bad RAM that failed memtest, and a GPU not seated properly! Good find! Was the GPU a chip, or a PCI/PCIe module?

Comment: @heynnema It's a PCIe card. An old gtx660ti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS ROG STRIX X370-F GAMING

You have a **really old** BIOS version 3803 from 1/22/2018. There's a newer BIOS available, version 5603, from 8/10/2020, and can be downloaded from [here](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x370-f-gaming-model/helpdesk_bios).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model # motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Note**: Some BIOS allow updating from directly in the current BIOS. Otherwise, if you don't have Windows, try FreeDOS at http://www.freedos.org/.

**MEMORY**

Ryzen 7 1700

Ryzen processors are very fussy about RAM.

The Corsair CMW16GX4M2C3200C16 doesn't appear in the supported memory list document. See CPU/memory docs [here](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x370-f-gaming-model/helpdesk_cpu).

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**DISK**

KINGSTON SA400S37120G (SBFK71E0)

**Note**: Check for firmware updates for the SSD. Get the `Kingston SSD Manager` [here](https://www.kingston.com/unitedstates/us/support/technical/ksm-firmware-update).

/dev/sdb2 is being remounted read-only.

The SMART data looks fine.

Let's check your Linux filesystem on /dev/sdb2...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**SWAP**

Your 2G /swapfile is too small. Let's increase it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

`memtest` did fail with the original memory. Memory replaced. `memtest` now runs without error.

**Update #2:**

Re-seated GPU.